# What's the tradeoff of storing a connection string vs the password as a secret?

Tags: configuration, azure, secrets-management

This is for an app service + database I am pushing up to Azure. I am using Key Vault + Managed Identity for the secrets. I have several connection strings in the secrets to ApplicationInsights, etc.

These connection strings have a key, password, etc. and also some non-secret settings like the endpoint, server, etc.

What are the trade-offs of putting the entire connection string in the key vault (what I am doing now) vs. putting just the confidential part of the connection string there and building it when needed in the app?

Comment: If someone would get access to the values the connection string is easy to identify and it also tells you username and the server the password belongs to. If you just have a password you have to put more effort into to understand what it is used for and which username belongs to it.